# Thinkpad W500 ATI Card Failing to Start on Windows 7 64-Bit

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, thinkpad, ati-mobility-radeon

Here's my setup:

- Thinkpad W500
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650 Running the latest Win7 drivers from ATI v 8.632.1.2000 (Aug. 17th!)
- Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Clean install.

In the device manager I'm seeing "The device cannot start. (Code 10)."

Comment: Do you have Switchable Graphics enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: run Windows Update.

Comment: Is this the 64-bit or 32-bit version?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Lenovo has finally released the updated Win 7 drivers to get switchable graphics back: http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-73641
Bon apetit!

Here's the deal:

Yes, I had switchable graphics and even with the latest version from Lenovo, they don't work.  They'll probably release another version in time for the official Win7 release.  I had to go into the BIOS setup and disable integrated graphics and set the primary grpahics adapter to Discrete.  The other options were Integrated and Switchable.  It was defaulting to Switchable.

So, I can switch the graphics adapters through the BIOS in the meantime.  Bit of a hassle but good to know there's a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues please provide feedback via the [Catalyst Crew Feedback](http://www.amd.com/us/CatalystCrewSurvey) website.

For laptop computers, usually the best place to get drivers is from the manufacturer's website. Unfortunately, I don't see Windows 7 drivers up on Lenovo's downloads for your model.

Here is a [Mobility Modder](http://orestech.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/overclocking-your-laptop-mobility-radeon/) link, but I have no idea if it will work for you.

Comment: Here is Code 10 Troubleshooting for Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943104/

Answer (score 0):

This post is timely for me.  I just got a W500 w/ switchable graphics and Vista Business (32 bit) and am seeing similar symptoms.

Viewing Device Manager/Display Adapters I see only the "Standard VGA Adapter".  BIOS set to "Switchable".  Even with ThinkPad Power Manager and Power Manager Drivers re-installed w/ latest and latest ATI/Intel combo drivers installed, system did not recognize either the integrated Intel video adapter or the ATI discrete adapter.

Changing the BIOS selection to "Discrete" results in zero video display post-BIOS.  Switching to "Integrated" has same issue as above - Intel adapter not recognized, still "Standard VGA Adapter".

I suspect problem with video adapter hardware as Vista won't recognize either.  Called support, did the level 1 uninstall, reinstall, reboot, reinstall, rinse, repeat cycle and they determined hw problem as well.

Nuts b/c just got laptop 2 days ago...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone take a look here:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/R400-T400-T500-W500-display-driver-quot-amdkmdap-quot-crashes/td-p/60899/page/44

I have had W500 for over a year now gave up on switchable just change it in BIOS when I need to.

Normally just run in "Discrete" and use Catalyst driver with Mobility Modder.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for switchable graphics on windows 7 here :
http://switchablegraphics.free.fr

Worked for me