# ThinkPad W500 series using FireGL V5700 Graphics Card trouble setting it

Tags: windows-7, bios, thinkpad, graphics

I've recently needed to actually set the discrete graphics on my W500...Before it came with Vista and you could do the `switchgraphics` thingie...then I went to a Win 7 Professional and didn't even bother fixing it.

Now I require the discrete graphics. I looked online everywhere and saw that there was no sure solution. In particular many solutions on Super User and other tech forms suggested changing the BIOS. I went into the BIOS and changed it from integrated to discrete but now I've come to another impasse - how do I manipulate the settings and/or increase the quality of the video card? By default doesn't, it just has some stupid settings.

As of this moment, my `dxdiag` window shows that I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650 - instead of FireGL V5700...I need to be able to increase my graphics output it seems laggy and stupid even when attempting to play the simplest of games.

Comment: "The FireGL V5700 graphics card is in fact a Mobility Radeon HD3650 with optimized drivers" so here you go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/31978/thinkpad-w500-ati-card-failing-to-start-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: I've checked that post out and attempted to see that fix through - nothing has changed nor has it detected the card that I actually have.

Comment: Did you check Lenovo forums? You surely are not only one having this issue.

Comment: I also checked them out. There wasn't anything of use on there.